# compress citation list in beamer

Tags: beamer, citing, cite-package

I am working on a presentation using beamer. I have a `bl.bib` file that has several entries in it.
I'm also using the cite package but when I try to cite several references together, i.e., `\cite{ref1, ref2,ref3}`, the result looks like [1,2,3] and not [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/em6BO.png)-[3].
Does anybody know how to make it look like [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/em6BO.png)-[3]?
Is this by purpose because it is not common to cite like this in presentations?

Minimal working example:
Tex file:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\usepackage{cite}
%Information to be included in the title page:
\title{Sample title}
\author{Anonymous}
\institute{Overleaf}
\date{2021}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}
Test \cite{a,b,c}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{References}
    \bibliography{bibliography}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

bibliography.bib file:

```
@article{a,
  title     = {a},
  author    = {a},
  journal   = {I},
  volume    = {7},
  pages     = {6},
  year      = {6},
  publisher = {IEEE}
}

@inproceedings{b,
  title     = {b},
  author    = {c},
  booktitle = {d},
  pages     = {123},
  year      = {2018}
}

@article{c,
  author  = {c},
  journal = {d},
  title   = {e},
  year    = {2004},
  volume  = {50},
  number  = {11},
  pages   = {1234}
}
```

result:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solved by using `\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}` instead of the `cite` package.