# Latex beamer: cite multiple references in one bracket

Tags: beamer, citing, presentations

i want to cite multiple references in one bracket on my beamer slide. For example, instead of `[1], [2], [3]` i want to have `[1-3]`. In my regular latex document, this seems to work by using the `cite` package, however, i can't figure out how to achieve the same with latex beamer.

Here is my example code. Note that I have a separate `.bib` file with entries like:

```
@article{cite1,
    title={Test},
    author={Test},
    year={1960}
}
```

This is my root document:

```
\documentclass[professionalfont, 10pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{cite}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
\cite{cit1,cit2,cit3} % gives [1], [2], [3]
\end{frame}
\section{References}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\tiny
    \bibliography{ref}
    % If too many references, use this command to resize：
    \tiny\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please prepare a complete and compilable [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that allows others to reproduce the output you get. Currently, the bib file is missing some entries and the keys don't match. If I use the code you provided so far, and make it compilable, I and up with an output like `[1, 2, 3]` instead of `[1], [2], [3]` which you claim to get.

Comment: You may be also interested in [compress citation list in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/597157/134144) or [What is the substitute for \usepackage{cite} in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/566573/134144)